# After RENAME(ing) a Table I'm forced to use quoted identifiers

Tags: postgresql, rename

After renaming a table in Postgres I'm experiencing a strange behaviour: if I reference the table without the quotes it doesn't work.

For example: the original name was «devices», after I've altered it to «Devices» the following SELECT breaks:

```
SELECT * from Devices
```

but this one

```
SELECT * from "Devices"
```

works as expected.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the manual, [identifiers are lower-cased unless quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

When you renamed it you did a `RENAME TO "Devices"`, thus making the name mixed-case. You must now refer to it in quoted mixed case everywhere.

To PostgreSQL all these are names for the `devices` table:

- `devices`
- `DEVICES`
- `Devices`
- `DeViCES`

but these are names for separate tables with mixed-case names:

- `"Devices"`
- `"DEVICES"`

This is according to the SQL standard except that SQL requires implementations to `UPPER CASE` un-quoted names, where PostgreSQL for historical reasons `lower cases` them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rename it again to `devices` (lower case without double quotes). Then you it will be possible to refer to it in any case you want including mixed case:

```
select * from dEvIceS
```